# Cannot create Hive external table using jdbcStorageHandler

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running a small cluster in Amazone EMR in order to play with Apache Hive 2.3.5.  It is my understanding that Apache Hive can import data from a remote database and have the cluster to run queries.  I was following an example that is provided in Apache Hive web documentation (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/JdbcStorageHandler) and created the following code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_table
(
  col1 int,
  col2 string,
  col3 date
)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.JdbcStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'hive.sql.database.type'='POSTGRES',
    'hive.sql.jdbc.driver'='org.postgresql.Driver',
    'hive.sql.jdbc.url'='jdbc:postgresql://<url>/<dbname>',
    'hive.sql.dbcp.username'='<username>',
    'hive.sql.dbcp.password'='<password>',
    'hive.sql.table'='<dbtable>',
    'hive.sql.dbcp.maxActive'='1'
);
```

But I get the following error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property hive.sql.query is required.)
```

According to the documentation, I need to specify either “hive.sql.table” or “hive.sql.query” to tell how to get data from jdbc database.  But if I replace hive.sql.table with hive.sql.query I get the following error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.conf.DatabaseType.POSTGRES)
```

I tried looking in the web for a solution and it doesn't look like anyone experience the same issues that I am having.  Do I need to modify a config file or am I missing something critical in my code?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using a version of the jar which doesn't support POSTGRES.

1. Download the latest jar from this link:
   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc-handler/3.1.2/hive-jdbc-handler-3.1.2.jar
2. Put this downloaded jar into a hdfs location.
3. Run hive normally.
4. Run command: add jar ${HDFS_PATH_TO_DOWNLOADED_JAR}
5. Run your create table command

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue and this worked for me, but Hive does not seem to push down predicates to the postgres database, maybe it can only do it for MYSQL?

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue.