# EMR - Cannot create external Hive table using jdbcstoragehandler

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I am trying to create an external hive table on postgres.
My first error got resolved as per answer in below topic:
[Cannot create Hive external table using jdbcStorageHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107669/cannot-create-hive-external-table-using-jdbcstoragehandler)

But I hit another issue:

java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.conf.DatabaseType.postgres**)

Surprisingly could not find anything on this issue so far in any forums.

Anyone encountered this error on EMR and resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it finally and posting answer in case it will help someone.

Root cause was the conflicting old version of same jar file left in hive lib directory. Hence it was not picking the new jar files and rather refering old one.

After I deleted the old jar, problem is resolved.